Understanding a particular way of solving $(4 + \sqrt{15})^x + (4 - \sqrt{15})^x = 62 $
This is the question. It wasn't hard to solve. I used basic algebra knowledge to solve it.

What is the value of $x$ so that the following equality holds?
$$(4 + \sqrt{15})^x + (4 - \sqrt{15})^x = 62 $$

Then I read the comments to see what others might add or if there is anything new I could learn and, I saw this comment which explains a shorter method which is very hard for me to understand. I feel like it is legit since the creator also hearted his comment

Transcribed:

Define $Z_n=x^n+\dfrac{1}{x^n}$, $Z_0=2$, then $$Z_{n+1}=Z_n Z_1-Z_{n-1}$$ Here, $Z_1=8$. [Observe that] $Z_2 =Z_1 Z_1 - Z_0=62$, hence, $n=2$.

I don't understand this approach. Please help me to understand it.
Here is the link to the Spencer's Academy YouTube video "A very nice olympiad question", in case you want to check it out.

FYI, assuming my suggested correction is what's intended, then an Approach0 search shows Solve $(4 + \sqrt15)^x + (4 - \sqrt15)^x =62$, where this answer there provides some theoretical backing for the recurrence relation $Z(n+1)=Z(n)Z(1)-Z(n-1)$. Regardless, you can easily verify this by just substituting in, and multiplying out, to show that $Z(n)Z(1)$ is the same as $Z(n+1)+Z(n-1)$.

Going forward, with your future MathSE postings, please make more of an effort to proofread your posted question.  See (for example) the glaring mistake that you made in  posting the question, that is identified near the start of the Steve Kass.

@JohnOmielan sorry my mistake. It is $$(4+√15)x+(4−√15)x.$$. I just copy pasted and didn't notice the mistake

I think the comment is very abbreviated, and not a lot shorter.
First of all, the question in the video is to find $x$ if $$(4 + \sqrt{\color{red}{15}})^x + (4 - \sqrt{\color{red}{15}})^x = 62.$$ It turns out that $(4 + \sqrt{15})\cdot(4 - \sqrt{15})=1$, so we can
first rewrite the equation as, $$\left((4 + \sqrt{15})^x\right)+\left((4 - \sqrt{15})^x\right)=62,\mbox{ and then it becomes}$$
$$\left((4 + \sqrt{15})^x\right)+\left({1\over(4 + \sqrt{15})^x}\right)=62.$$
Let $p=\left((4 + \sqrt{15})\right)$, and it becomes $$ p^n+{1\over p^n}=62.$$
Write $\displaystyle Z(n) = p^n+{1\over p^n}$. Note that, $Z(0)=2$ and $Z(1)=(4+\sqrt{15})+(4-\sqrt{15})=8$. Further note that $$Z(n)Z(1)=\left(p^n+{1\over p^n}\right)\cdot\left(p+{1\over p}\right)\\=p^{n+1}+p^{n-1}+{1\over p^{n-1}}+{1\over p^{n+1}}=\left(p^{n+1}+{1\over p^{n+1}}\right)+\left(p^{n-1}+{1\over p^{n-1}}\right)\\=Z(n+1)+ Z(n-1).$$  Let $n=1$ to get $Z(1)Z(1)=Z(2)+Z(0)$, or $8\cdot8=Z(2)+2$, and therefore, $Z(2)=62.$
Rewriting in terms of $x$ and what $p$ was, then,
$$\left((4 + \sqrt{15})^2\right)+\left({1\over(4 + \sqrt{15})^2}\right)=\left((4 + \sqrt{15})^2\right)+\left({(4 - \sqrt{15})^2}\right)=62.$$

Thanks, @JohnOmielan. I think I fixed it, but comment back or propose an edit if not!

You're welcome. Thanks for making that fix. It all looks good to me now.

@SteveKass  (p^n+1+1/p^n+1)+(p^n−1+1/p^n−1), does not equal to Z(n+1)−Z(n−1), right? Isn't it Z(n+1)+Z(n−1)

No, it doesn't, and neither is $64 = 62 - 2.$ I've fixed the mistake, I hope! It should be $+$ as you note, and then the solution to $8\cdot8 = Z(2) + 2$ correctly yields $Z(2)=62.$ Classic mistake of mine, filling in the blanks between something and the known answer...
